# MapTips missing from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, maptips

I just looked for MapTips in ArcGIS Pro 1.2 and have not been able to find them in either the application or its documentation.

Has anyone found them in ArcGIS Pro 1.2, or know when/whether they are expected to be added?

For those unfamiliar with map tips, the [ArcMap documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/displaying-maptips.htm) describes them:

> MapTips pop up as you hover the pointer on a feature, providing a
>   quick way to see the name of that feature or a particular piece of
>   information without having to use the Identify tool or HTML pop-up
>   windows. ArcMap lets you choose which attribute field you want to
>   display as your MapTip.

Personally, I do not think that they are overly important to have, and am happy to just label or identify/popup to get the same/more info about visible features.

Comment: There appears to be a Display Field in the layer properties, but no map-tip that pops up the value in that field.  Possibly something that hasn't fully made it in yet.

Comment: @Midavalo that's the place where I think they should manifest themselves too - when ArcGIS Pro was close to its first release I think someone told me that they were not ready yet.  I've never found them overly important and am happy to just label or identify/popup to get the same/more info about visible features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapTips do not exist in ArcGIS Pro and at this point there are not any plans to add them. If you feel differently about their importance, I'd recommend logging an idea on [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com).